# Select latest child for each parent optimization

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mariadb-10.5

I have 2 tables, a keyword table and a keyword position table

keyword structure

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords`
(
    `id`      bigint(20) UNSIGNED                     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `keyword` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

keyword_positions  structure

```
CREATE TABLE `keyword_positions`
(
    `id`         bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `keyword_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `position`   int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This is how I preform my select

```
SELECT `keywords`.*,
       kp.position AS kp_position
FROM `keywords`
         LEFT JOIN `keyword_positions` AS `kp`
                   ON `kp`.`keyword_id` = `keywords`.`id`
                       AND `kp`.`id` =
                           (SELECT MAX(ikp.id)
                            FROM keyword_positions AS ikp
                            WHERE keywords.id = ikp.keyword_id)
```

Can this query be optimized further? it runs for about 800 MS

Comment: There's no index?

Comment: both ids are unique and auto incrementing, updating my question, thank you

Comment: What is the reason to have separate table for positions?

Comment: I have many positions, one per day

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get much better performance when I don't use `MAX`, This is my new query

```sql
SELECT `keywords`.*,
       kp.position AS kp_position
FROM `keywords`
         left join `keyword_positions` as `kp`
                   on `kp`.`keyword_id` = `keywords`.`id`
                       and `kp`.`id` = (SELECT ikp.id
                                        FROM keyword_positions AS ikp
                                        WHERE keywords.id = ikp.keyword_id
                                        ORDER BY ikp.id DESC
                                        LIMIT 1)
```

runs for 30-60 MS

Answer (score 0):

The innermost subquery will probably run a lot faster if `ikp` had

```
INDEX(keyword_id, id)
```

With that, the Optimizer can do `MAX()` much more efficiently.